# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS compatibility with Dell PowerEdge R650

Tags: 18.04, server, dell, lts, compatibility

Anyone know or have any experience running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with newly release Dell PowerEdge R650?
In dell compatibility and also in Ubuntu compatibility, only Ubutun 20.04 is reported as compatible.

Comment: If newly released hardware then a newer Ubuntu release is preferably if not "mandatory". You may get away with a fully updated 18.04 with the newest kernel available and enjoy it while supported (~1 year left) but if Dell themselves say "Ubuntu 20.04" then you're on your own using any older release. Dell professional customer support (servers) will NOT give you support for 18.04.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu)